# any help on how to build a rack server?

Tags: rack, hardware

i have no experience with servers at all, but i would like to know how to build a rack server in my freezing garage, i have done some research and bought a cabinet, an Ethernet switch and loads of ssd's, at the moment i have about 200 USB keys and 20 external hdd's i store files for friends and family as i am the best with pc's in our community, i still don't know how to build a server though.any more components i need please list them, i will find it self explanatory to set up i guess.

thanks, Jason

Comment: Someone just asked a somewhat similar question over on our meta.  http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6597/can-i-ask-about-server-assembling-training-courses You should review that and the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Don't. Buy a used HP, Dell, or IBM rack server. You can get a good one, 3-4 years old for $250 on ebay.
Also, HDs cost about $15/year just to sit there spinning. "loads" of them are going to cost "loads" to run.

See also: [Choosing a Server Chassis based on Server Board's Requirements](https://serverfault.com/questions/623800/choosing-a-server-chassis-based-on-server-boards-requirements/623816#623816)